# Exporting .EML from Windows Live Mail to Outlook corrupted emails

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, file-corruption, windows-live-mail

Before anyone says go through 1 by 1. I have 25,115 emails to transfer. So it's not physically possible.

Okay I am trying to export and get my old man off Windows Live Mail and onto Outlook. These Emails are in .eml format. When exporting  it freeze up. After doing some research it appears to be due to corrupted emails. https://i.stack.imgur.com/470xN.jpg

I DO NOT WANT TO RECOVER THEM. I want to incinerate (delete) them. A few emails here and there do not bother me. But I don't want to dump the whole archive.
As I mentioned going 1 by 1 is not a simple task so anything that can scan and remove these emails would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free [Import Outlook Messages from EML Files](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesImportEML/) utility to import your EML files into Outlook. It just skips corrupted EMLs reporting them to the Output. I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers.

Comment: That would be good apart from the fact that the free version is limited to 10 messages. As I said, I have 25k to deal with.

Comment: @GideonSassoon, free version is not limited to a number of messages at all. It can import the unlimited number of emails. There is a commercial trial ReliefJet Essentials that limits the number of emails but the OutlookFreeware tool is unlimited.

Comment: Hi @thims I've tried your tool out as far as I can see there is a limit of 100 messages. [Image](https://imgur.com/a/Pye5mSO)

Comment: @GideonSassoon, yes some limitations in our free utilities were introduced last year.

Answer (score 0):

You can export EML from Windows Live Mail to Outlook. Windows Live Mail, part of Windows Live Essentials, is a successor to Outlook Express and Windows Live Desktop.

1. Start Outlook.
2. Start Windows Live Mail.
3. In Windows Live Mail, click File or press ALT+M to show the File menu bar.
4. On the File menu, point to Export, and then click Messages.
5. In the Windows Live Mail Export Wizard, click Microsoft Exchange, and then click Next.
6. Click OK when you see the following message:
   This will export messages from Windows Live Mail to Microsoft Outlook or Microsoft Exchange.
7. To specify the files that you want to export, click All, and then click OK. Or, click Selected Folders, select the folders that you want to export, and then click OK.
8. In the Export Complete window, click Finish.

If you are facing any issue with manual method, then you go with **GainTools EML to PST converter Software**.